# Converting NSImage to CIImage without degraded quality

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image

I am trying to convert an NSImage to a CIImage. When I do this, there seems to be a huge loss in image quality. I think it is because of the "TIFFRepresentation". Does anyone have a better method? Thanks a lot.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[someSource dataRepresentation]];

NSData  * tiffData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
CIImage *backgroundCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:tiffData];

CIContext *ciContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] CIContext];  
[ciContext drawImage:backgroundCIImage atPoint:CGPointZero fromRect:someRect];
```

Comment: TIFF is a lossless bitmap container, so that seems like an unlikely culprit if the original image was a bitmap. In what way is the quality degraded?

Comment: The data source for the NSImage is a PDFPage. When I draw the CIImage, after converting from NSImage, the text in the image is very very blurry. Also I tried drawing out just the NSImage and there doesn't seem to be any loss in image quality. Therefore, I concluded that it must be the TIFF conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Basically, I render the pdf document two times its normal resolution offscreen and then capture the image displayed by the view. For a more detailed image, just increase the scaling factor. Please see the code below for the proof of concept. I didn't show the CIImage but once you get the bitmap, just use the CIImage method to create the CIImage from the bitmap.

```
    NSImage *pdfImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[[aPDFView activePage] dataRepresentation]];
    NSSize size = [pdfImage size];
    NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    imageRect.size.width *= 2; //Twice the scale factor
    imageRect.size.height *= 2; //Twice the scale factor

    PDFDocument *pageDocument = [[[PDFDocument alloc] init] autorelease];
    [pageDocument insertPage:[aPDFView activePage] atIndex:0];

    PDFView *pageView = [[[PDFView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [pageView setDocument:pageDocument];
    [pageView setAutoScales:YES];

    NSWindow *offscreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:imageRect 
                                                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                              backing:NSBackingStoreRetained
                                                                defer:NO];

    [offscreenWindow setContentView:pageView];
    [offscreenWindow display];
    [[offscreenWindow contentView] display]; // Draw to the backing buffer

    // Create the NSBitmapImageRep
    [[offscreenWindow contentView] lockFocus];

    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:imageRect];

    // Clean up and delete the window, which is no longer needed.
    [[offscreenWindow contentView] unlockFocus];

    [compositeImage TIFFRepresentation]];
    NSData *imageData = [rep representationUsingType: NSJPEGFileType properties: nil];
    [imageData writeToFile:@"/Users/David/Desktop/out.jpg" atomically: YES];

    [offscreenWindow release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is indeed converting to TIFF. PDF is a vector format, while TIFF is bitmap, so a TIFF will look blurry at larger sizes.

Your best bet is probably to get a CGImage from the NSImage and create the CIImage from that. Either that or just create the CIImage from the original data.

Comment: CGImages and CIImages are rasters, too. The questioner cannot perform this task without converting to a raster image, since the destination he wants is a raster image. (That said, going through CGImage instead of a TIFF representation probably is the correct solution, for performance reasons if nothing else.)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
NSData  * tiffData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
```

with

```
NSData  * tiffData = [image TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression: NSTIFFCompressionNone factor: 0.0f];
```

because [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/TIFFRepresentation) states that TIFFRepresentation uses the TIFF compression option associated with each image representation, which might not be NSTIFFCompressionNone.  Thus, you should be explicit about wanting the tiffData uncompressed.

Comment: I tried that and got the same result as before (degraded quality).